# In the TCP program of Vert.x, how to judge the idle timeout of the client?

Tags: java, vert.x

Use setIdleTimeout to set the client idle timeout time, but in the NetSocket .closeHandler method, how to confirm that the client's disconnection is due to the client idle timeout?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [wiremock](http://wiremock.org/docs/simulating-faults/) to inject faults and write test case around that